# Can't remove empty line break in textarea with Javascript replace method

Tags: javascript, replace, textarea

When I paste the following into the text area, when onblur it's supposed to tidy up the text pasted removing certain words, tab spaces and tidying up by placing each value separated by the tabs spaces into it's own line. But it always leaves a blank empty line at the very first line:

*Note: I can't seem to emulate tab spaces in html so you'll have to manually type the following in notepad to properly replicate my problem: where %%% replace with tab space in notepad then select-all and copy/paste into my  [js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/themeanfiddler/3PSzj/) textarea*

```
  Customer account %%% Name %%% Telephone   %%%  Street name %%% City %%% postcode%%% 1234LA3 %%% KCI ASDFGHJ %%% 1234567890 %%% 10 EXAMPLE ST %%% EXAMPLE CITY %%% 1234
```

when you onblur
It ends up looking like this:

```
1234LA3 
KCI ASDFGHJ 
1234567890 
10 EXAMPLE ST 
EXAMPLE CITY 
1234
```

notice blank empty space above '1234LA3'.

I've already tried adding \n\r in my .replace() method but still doesn't seem to filter out this empty line.

any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Comment: You said onblur...thats ondblclick. You really should separate your javascript into a function that you call in your element's inline event handler...much easier to manage and reuse.

Comment: You can use just "\n", like: http://jsfiddle.net/3PSzj/1/

Comment: I tried but like with Daedalus it just creates more empty lines above the text..

Comment: thank you everyone, I combined Daedulus's line removal and Manatax's tab removal together. Works like a charm now...  http://jsfiddle.net/themeanfiddler/3PSzj/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
value=value.replace(/^(\r\n)|(\n)/,'');
```

Seems to do the trick.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3PSzj/4/)

Also, you can emulate tab characters in html with `&#09;`, not to mention that you don't need to prefix javascript in events with `javascript:`.

Comment: doesn't seem to work with the rest of my code. Seems to just create more empty lines instead of removing it.

Comment: @like-a-trainee I altered the demo to a more-up-to-date one.  Please see that instead.

Comment: @like-a-trainee What browser are you using?  The above was tested in IE9, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: there's still that empty gap above '1234LA3'
btw: I'm running IE8

Comment: I'm using IE8. I'm looking at your example http://jsfiddle.net/3PSzj/2/. When I DblClick I still see an empty gap above the text, above '1234LA3

Comment: @like-a-trainee Sorry about that, it should be working now, I had the wrong link and code for a second.

Comment: Manatax solution works, but I've missed a new line break after postcode how would I modify it to remove new line breaks in the pasted text?

Comment: @like-a-trainee The only thing after postcode is a tab in my testing, could you perhaps post an example to go off of?

Comment: Bingo!! you got it! Thank you! Works like a charm! :)

Comment: @like-a-trainee Glad I could assist.

Answer (score 2):

Or just add \t after the first replace:

```
value=value.replace(/(Customer account\t|Name\t|Street name\t|Telephone\t|City\t|postcode\t|Extension\t)/g,'');
```

The problem arises, because you have a tab after the last title.

Comment: there is something I missed in my example. After postcode there is a new line break after the tab. Your code seems to work, but I still see a gap above, it seems there's something hidden I can't see. But I suspect it's because of the new line break after postcode. And that's why I'm still getting the gap at my end.

Comment: thank you your solution works perfect combined with Daedulus line removal method. I just added it to the onDblClick= event. like so: onDblclick="value=value.replace(/(Customer account\t|Name\t|Street name\t|Telephone\t|City\t|postcode\t|Extension\t)/g,'');value=value.replace(/\t/g,'\r');value=value.replace(/[\n\r](?!\w)/gi,'');value=value.replace(/^(\r\n)|(\n)/,'');"

Comment: you are welcome =)
Sometimes is better to fix the problem rather than the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

A regex would work like so, if you were to go that way:

```
str.replace(/^$/m, '');
```

Yes?  Someone sanity check this for me?

Comment: this didn't work either. Yeilds the same result as Set Sail Media, and Daedulus's suggestion. Still getting that gap above '1234LA3'