# Removing blank lines from textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

First, I've tried all possible solutions that I've found here or Google, but no one seems to work for me.

To be clear, I need to remove every empty lines from a text area. 
This is what I've done so far:

```
<textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="14" id="text" placeholder="Here goes our query" ></textarea>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#text').focusout(function () {
        var text = $('#text').val();

        text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

        alert('done');
    });
});
```

I get successful alert on end, but those empty lines are still there. Is regexp correct ?
My knowledge for js is not that big, so I need help :(

Comment: See [*JavaScript: how to use a regular expression to remove blank lines from a string?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369642/javascript-how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-remove-blank-lines-from-a-string) and [*Can't remove empty line break in textarea with Javascript replace method*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205169/cant-remove-empty-line-break-in-textarea-with-javascript-replace-method). Also, [*jquery text().replace('','') not working*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025944/jquery-text-replace-not-working).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp
>
> The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

So you are not actually changing the textarea value.

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#text').focusout(function () {
        var text = $('#text').val();
        text = text.replace(/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/gm, "");
        $(this).val(text);
    });
});
```

[The regex is from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/816102/3103257)

Answer (score 3):

The solution from @adam has a bug, the new line character for a valid row will be removed as well. Example:

Input:

```
1
2

3
4

5
6
```

Result with: `text.replace(/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/gm, "");`

[image]

However using a similar regex will solve it: `text.replace(/^\s*$(?:\r\n?|\n)/gm, "");`

[image]

Complete example with plain JavaScript:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" oninput="validateValue(this)"></textarea>

<script>
    function validateValue(elem) {
        const value = elem.value;
        const newVal = value.replace(/^\s*$(?:\r\n?|\n)/gm, "");

        elem.value = newVal;
    }
</script>
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369725/3850405

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#text').focusout(function () {
        var text = $('#text').val();

        var modifiedtext=text.replace(/ /g, "");
         $(this).val(modifiedtext);
        alert('done');

    });
});
```